# Is it possible to merge a specific revision that only exists as subset of a former merge?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

In my scenario, I have three branches `b1`, `b2` and `b3`.
I created three files A,B and C in `b1` and committed them separately, resulting in this log:

```
svn log ^/branches/b1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r14
C created
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r13
B created
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r12
A created
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I change to the branch `b2` and merge the changes from `b1`

```
svn merge ^/branches/b1
```

which results in r15

```
svn log ^/branches/b2
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r15
Merged from b1: A,B,C
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I would like to merge **only revision r12** to the branch `b3`. I can see all the revisions 12,13 and 14 using `svn log -g ^/branches/b2`.
When I execute the merge command, only the mergeinfo is written:

```
svn merge -c 12 ^branches/b2
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r12 into '.':
 U   .
```

But I want **only** the exact revision with file A merged from `b2` into `b3`.
If I get this right, this is not possible since r12 does not exist in the `b2` path. So there are only two ways of achieving what I want:

- Merge r12 from `b1` to `b3`
- Merge and commit each revision of `b1` separately to `b2`, then select the "new" revisions there

I have seen this: [SVN. Merge every single branch revision separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314756/svn-merge-every-single-branch-revision-separately) which gives me an idea of how to implement a script that eases the latter option.

Isn't there any possibility to realize this "natively" with svn?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can see all the revisions 12,13 and 14 using `svn log -g ^/branches/b2`

But for (my sample)

```
>svn log -g -q -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r9 | Badger | 2014-03-09 02:01:44 +0600 (Вс, 09 мар 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/b2
   A /branches/b2/A.txt (from /branches/b1/A.txt:8)
   A /branches/b2/B.txt (from /branches/b1/B.txt:8)
   A /branches/b2/C.txt (from /branches/b1/C.txt:8)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r8 | Badger | 2014-03-09 02:00:16 +0600 (Вс, 09 мар 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches/b1/C.txt
Merged via: r9
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | Badger | 2014-03-09 01:59:56 +0600 (Вс, 09 мар 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches/b1/B.txt
Merged via: r9
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | Badger | 2014-03-09 01:59:38 +0600 (Вс, 09 мар 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches/b1/A.txt
Merged via: r9
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2014-03-09 01:56:48 +0600 (Вс, 09 мар 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches/b1 (from /trunk:2)
Merged via: r9
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2014-03-09 01:57:41 +0600 (Вс, 09 мар 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches/b2 (from /trunk:3)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2014-03-09 01:55:10 +0600 (Вс, 09 мар 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Main.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2014-03-09 01:52:47 +0600 (Вс, 09 мар 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches
   A /tags
   A /trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

presence revisions 6-8 in log for b2 after merge **must** means **nothing**

- `Merged via: r9` in output
- unrelated to b2 paths in affected files

is good indication of *merged into*, but *not belonging to* branch revisions

If you want merge changes from one specific revision into another node, you **must** to use revision from  node, in which it really exist (in your case - b1)